# Cable Tester, Master unit lights up even when the remote unit is not plugged in

Tags: networking, cat6, power-over-ethernet

I recently started a new job and one of our security cameras went down. I am trying to work out why and want to find out what port the POE cable from the camera plugs into in the switch in the server room.

I am using a cable tester with a Master and Remote unit and its my understanding that when you plug the Remote in one end (By the camera) and the Master in the corresponding other end (In the server room) the lights should blink sequentially in order.

However the issue i am having is that my Master unit seems to blink sequentially with several cables i have tried which means i cannot identify the correct cable.

Why is this the case ? Surely if it is the incorrect cable the lights should not blink at all ?

Answer (score 1):

The Master will always blink, this is to indicate that it is functioning and what it is doing. The Remote will also light up, but only once the signal is received that the master is sending out.

In order to understand your cable tester, grab a short UTP cable and test it so you can see both the Master and Remote.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tested the device and when i plug a cable in to the Master without plugging it into the remote unit also it does not blink sequentially. You only get the standard power LED. When i plug it into the remote unit also they both blink sequentially down the numbers 1-8. My issue is that this seems to happen when i plug several different cables in my server room into the master where they all arent connect to the Remote unit, only 1 of them is and i cannot work out which one it is.

Comment: Yes, I understood your quesion. You want to put the master on the end that won't change, then go to the other end with the remote unit, and plug it on. When you plug it in and the remote starts to light up, you got the right cable. If it does not light up, switch to another cable.